# how to write math equations in wordpress (like latex)?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i want to write math equations in Wordpress .(like latex)
for example: `\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k}`

how can i write that?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Use+LaTeX+in+Wordpress&t=hb&ia=web

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way for you is to put into the equation as an image. I suggest that you use the following link.[Online Equation](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)